# Load Raster from MS SQL Server into QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

Attempting to connect to an MS SQL database in QGIS. 
Database connects fine, and all the vector items load correctly.
Rasters, however, appear as polygons, geometry column shows as FOOTPRINT, and when loaded in they are a basic polygon of the raster footprint, not the raster file.
It's from an organisational server, set up for use in Arc as an SDE, but personal requirements mean working in QGIS would be better. The rasters are  in SDR format - is it a case this isn't supported in QGIS?
Anyone able to advise on how to load the rasters from the MS SQL Server?

The system is already pre-set up by our company in Arc 10.3.1 - we navigate in the catalog to a location where there are  sde files - Properties in Arc describe it as a SQL Server Enterprise Geodatabase. The connection properties give the server instance
Loaded into QGIS 3.4 via the datasource manager using the server instance as the host, selecting the required database, and have tried testing the 4 database options with no luck

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to clarify how you loaded this data. If you used Esri tools, at which version? Esri doesn't support rasters in SQL Server any more, and hasn't emphasized the capability since ArcGIS Server started supporting caches at 9.2.

Comment: Additional details added - using ArcMap 10.3.1 - not much experience in Arc, this is pre-set up by our organisation